# How can I access the raw profile photo for any given user?

Tags: users, user-profile, author

I am using the profile photo on users' posts (author image) and I would like to provide a link to download a larger image. I am currently able to get the "full" size of the cropped image like this:

```
<img src="{{ entry.author.getPhotoUrl('original') }}" alt="{{ entry.title }}">
```

Is there a way to get to the image that *looks* like is stored here:

```
/craft/storage/userphotos/*
```

Comment: I don't believe so. You might be able to do something creative with a plugin, but I'm not entirely certain that would work either. User Profile images are a special case, since they're not regular Assets. if I remember correctly, I _believe_ that those might get transitioned to regular Assets in Craft 3. (I say that with about 60% confidence.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can get the full cropped version of the image with `author.getPhotoUrl('original')`, but Craft doesn't keep a copy of the original un-cropped version of the image around.

And [Lindsey is more than 60% correct](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17075/how-can-i-access-the-raw-profile-photo-for-any-given-user#comment23612_17075)... user photos are [1st class Asset citizens](https://craftcms.com/3/changelog#build2915) in Craft 3, making this less awkward.